# Check if Control.Text is to long to be shown

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to do some automatic tests if the strings of a translated Application still fits the existing UI. The translation process just takes an existing resource assembly translates the contained resources and creates a new resources assembly for the new language. Easy but that way there is no garantee that the translations still fits into the UI (the UI is not involved in the translation process) and might get truncated all over the place. So for an automatic check i would need an idea on how to find truncated Text on the UI.

I tried so far:

- Measuring the client size of a control, measuring the text length and
  compare them. Doesn't work since there seem to be no way to find out
  the ~real~ client size of a control that is used for putting text on
  it (For a Button its not just Size minus Padding for example)
- Setting AutoSize to true and checking if the control grows. That
  would only    work for non-wordwrapping controls and there seem to be
  no sharp    limit here. A control might grow to fit the Text on its
  surface when    setting autosize but the Text was fitting before
  also. The margins    might have been pretty narrow but the Text where
  fitting.

Are there more idea that might work? Or are there some tweeks that might make the above mentioned ways work? Would be great if there where a simple  Win API method i could call that would just give me the actual shown text of a control not the text a programmer/programm whishes to be shown on a control.

Comment: Why do you need to check for truncated text if you can enable `AutoSize` on your controls and have your UI adjust itself to longer text automatically?

Comment: I tried to set autosize just for testing its not set on the real application. The test would have been something like, finding all Forms/UserControls in an assembly, instanciate them, show them, set AutoSize an all Controls and compare the size before autosize and after. And as i said that doesn't work well. Controls that have AutoSize set already aren't tested for obvious reasons. They are safe.

Comment: Downvoters please comment so i can fix the question if you see a problem with it.

Comment: Yeah, I understand you're building tool to detect truncated text, presumably used to tell translators to shorten those translations. But what I mean is: if you can make the real application auto-size all its controls, then there wouldn't be a need for such a tool, right? Or do you run into issues with overlapping controls in that case? (I'm not so familiar with WinForms)

Comment: I can make single controls of the UI autosize at runtime in the context of the testtool to see what happens (do controls grow for example). The actual application won't autosize its controls it hasn't been designed that way in most parts. And yes simply changing Autosizing everywhere results in overlapping and other kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Get the amount of the characters from the non translated version and differentiate them against the length of the translated version then multiply the current controls width by the difference. It could look something like this.

```
float scalingAmount = 0.1 //This is just an example value, you'd probably want to adjust this yourself
float difference = oldLabel.Text.Length - label.Text.Length;
label.Width = oldLabel.Width * (difference/scalingAmmount)
```

Comment: That might give good results with a monospaced font. But those aren't used in typical UI's. Tahoma surely isn't monospaced. But yes the idea behind that, not directly compare against the UI but compare with an existing translation, a one i know of that it fits, is another option.

Comment: @Ralf Indeed. you might need to look into font classes to see how to get that length.